# Setting html preamble in org-publish

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

So I am trying to set a html preamble on my org-publish, and I am using the following code:

```lisp
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(("org-notes"
         :base-directory "~/Projects/blog/"
         :base-extendion "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/Public/"
         :recursive t
         :makeindex t
         :html-preamble "This is just a test"
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html)
        ("org-static"
         :base-directory "~/org/"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
         :publishing-directory "~/Public/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)
        ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))))
```

However, nothing shows up. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You have two `:html-preamble` settings: does anything happen if you get rid of the second one?

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake. I just checked it and it was not it.

Comment: So I copied your settings (with changes to the paths of course), created a dummy org file `foo.org` in the `blog` directory and published the project. I get a `foo.html` file in the `Public` directory that contains this: `<body>
<div id="preamble" class="status">
This is just a test
</div>...` - so AFAICT it works fine. If you cannot reproduce this, I'd suggest you start with `emacs -q` and possibly a very minimal init file, if you need one to load Org mode (if you are using the Org mode that's built-in to emacs, you should not need *any* init file) and try publishing.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that the problem was that, because I was making no changes on the posts, org-mode saw no need to recompile it. 
To overcome this, just add the force flag to the org-publish function.

Comment: This gets me all the time. It would be cool if the caching mechanism could check whether the project in `org-publish-project-alist` has changed since the last invocation.