# Org publish html preamble navigation bar does not work

Tags: html, org-publish

I tried to change html preamble by adding a new item to the nav bar, but publish is not updating the navigation bar.

I found [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58549/setting-html-preamble-in-org-publish), but I didn't know how to add a "force flag" to org-publish function. But I'm not sure if that's the problem.

My  org-publish file below. I'm trying to add one more item to the list in the preamble.

```
(require 'ox-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(

("org-notes"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
 :auto-preamble nil
 :html-preamble "<div id=\"navbar\"> <ul>
  <li><a href=\"index.html\">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"blog.html\">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"/iletisim.html\">İletişim</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"/hakkinda.html\">Hakkında</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</div>
"
 )

("org-static"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
 )

("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))

       ;; ... add all the components here (see below)...

      ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `C-u M-x org-publish-current-project` or `C-u M-x org-publish-current-file` to force the publishing of the current project (the project associated with the current file) or just the current file.

Alternatively, you can forego using timestamps for checking whether something is updated. Setting

```el
(setq org-publish-use-timestamps-flag nil)
```

will *always* publish everything (which might not be a good idea if the project is large and takes a while to publish).

You can also clean out the timestamps to force publishing even if `org-publish-use-timestamps-flag` is set to the default `t` value. The timestamps are saved in the directory `~/.org-timestamps` by default: check the value of `org-publish-timestamp-directory` for the actual value. You can just delete the `<project>.cache` file for your project (`org-notes` in your case).

Comment: Ok. Would deleting `org-notes.cache` file have any side effects?

Comment: It will be regenerated the next time you publish, so I don't think so. It is only used to decide whether to publish or not.